# The validator is not working - Spring MVC 3

Tags: spring, controller, tags, validation

I want to add a user to my database so i create a form with a validator but this one is not working, when i leave some feilds empty and i click on button submit nothing happend i just have this error :

```
Etat HTTP 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [insert into utilisateurs (id,login, password, nom, prenom,enable) values (?,?,?,?,?,?)]; Column 'login' cannot be null; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'login' cannot be null
```

this is the form  :

```
<form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/ajouter_user" method="post" commandName="user">

            <table id="tabmenu">


        <tr> 
            <td id="idtab">Nom :</td> 
             <td><form:input type="text" path="nom" class="round default-width-input"/></td>
             <td><form:errors path="nom" cssClass="errorbox" /></td>                        
        </tr>
        <tr>            
         <td id="idtab">Prénom :</td>
         <td> <form:input type="text" path="prenom" class="round default-width-input"/></td>
         <td><form:errors path="prenom" cssClass="errorbox" /></td> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td id="idtab">Login :</td>
        <td> <form:input type="text" path="login" cssClass="round default-width-input"/></td>
        <td><form:errors path="login" class="errorbox" /></td>  
        <tr>
        <td id="idtab">Password :</td>
        <td> <form:input type="password" path="password" class="round default-width-input"/></td>
        <td><form:errors path="password" cssClass="errorbox" /></td>    
        </tr>
        <tr>
    <td id="idtab">Séléctionner un rôle :</td>
    <td> <form:select path="role">
                        <form:option value="" label="Selectionner" />
                        <form:option value="1">Administrateur</form:option>
                        <form:option value="2">Simple utilisateur</form:option>
        </form:select></td>
    <td><form:errors path="role" cssClass="errorbox" /></td>    
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td id="idtab">Désactivé :</td> 
        <td><form:input type="checkbox" value="true" checked="checked" path="enable"/>  Oui</td>    
    </tr>
     <tr></tr>
     <tr></tr>
                 <tr> <td colspan=2><input class="button round blue image-right ic-right-arrow" type="submit" value="Créer"></td></tr>

            </table>
        </form:form>
            <div class="success"><c:out value="${msg_success}"  /></div>
```

The validator :

```
package gestion.delegation.validator;

import gestion.delegation.domaine.User;

import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.validation.ValidationUtils;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;

public class AddUserValidator implements Validator{

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {

        return User.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object obj, Errors err) {
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(err, "nom", "name.required","Choisissez un nom");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(err, "prenom", "prenom.required", "Choisissez un prenom");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(err, "login", "login.required", "Choisissez un login");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(err, "password", "password.required", "Choisissez un password");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(err, "role", "role.required", "Choisissez un role");

    }

}
```

and this is the controller :

```
package gestion.delegation.controller;

import gestion.delegation.domaine.User;
import gestion.delegation.service.ImplIUserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;




@Controller
public class GestionUserController{

    private ImplIUserService userservice;

    @Autowired
    public void setImplserv(ImplIUserService userservice) {
        this.userservice = userservice;
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/ajouter_user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String add(ModelMap model) {
        User user = new User();
        userservice.AddUser(user);
        String msg= "Vous avez ajouter un utilisateur avec succès !";
        model.addAttribute("msg_success",msg);
        return "gestionUser";

    }
}




public void AddUser(User user) {

        final String User_INSERT1 = "insert into utilisateurs (id,login, password, nom, prenom,enable) "
                + "values (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        final String User_INSERT2="insert into roles (id,login,role) values(?,?,?)";
        /*
         * On récupère et on utilisera directement le jdbcTemplate
         */
        getJdbcTemplate()
                .update(User_INSERT1,
                        new Object[] { user.getId(), user.getLogin(),
                                user.getPassword(), user.getNom(),
                                user.getPrenom(), user.getEnable(),
                                 });
        getJdbcTemplate().update(User_INSERT2, new Object[]{ user.getId(),user.getLogin(),user.getRole()});
    }
```

It show me that  The error is here : **.update(User_INSERT1,**
So where is the wrong here ? Please Help ! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your add method passes the 'user' object to the 'UserService.AddUser' method, but the 'user' object is basically empty - it was only created on the previous line of code :)

```
User user = new User();
userservice.AddUser(user);
```

Comment: But I think the form has to set fields values of the User object ?

Comment: I resolve the problem it was the validator I didn't create an instanse of it in the controller class. Thank you